# Handle user login with token base authentication (multiple ViewControllers) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, django-rest-framework, swift5

I'm working on an application and having issues with logging in and moving to the main ViewController.

**Goal:** Display the LoginViewController if the user has not logged in, once signed in, segue to the CannabisListViewController.

Right now, when I select the Login button in the simulator, the token & the token's expiration date is printed out in the header. I've also verified that the backend generates a new token.

**API response**

```
Server WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.2
Set-Cookie csrftoken=XelHDMTehmhJxLe5q6uqDYCymZV1iUaKNzRqtOcYYrmMvNkKTnuRbkjHEM2LR8Xo; expires=Fri, 26 Feb 2021 03:58:03 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax, sessionid=5cu84ccaquq46ga8kazfjequ136y24g1; expires=Fri, 13 Mar 2020 03:58:03 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Date Fri, 28 Feb 2020 03:58:03 GMT
Content-Type application/json
Content-Length 50
Vary Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Allow POST, OPTIONS
```

**Backend:**
Django/Django Rest Framework & Django Rest Auth

**Where I'm at currently:**
I'm also using UserDefaults to store what I think is the token, but I'm not sure if I'm implementing it properly or how to store the token so I can check if it exists and change the ViewController based on that.

**SceneDelegate**

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {


        // IF USER IS LOGGED IN
        if let _ = userToken?.key {

            // CREATE TAB BAR //
            let tabController = UITabBarController()

            // Instantiate the storyboards
            let cannabisStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Cannabis", bundle: nil)
            let profileStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)


             // Instantiate the view controllers to storyboards
             let cannabisVC = cannabisStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Cannabis") as! CannabisViewController
             let profileVC = profileStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profile") as! ProfileViewController


             // Displays the items in below order in tab bar
             let vcData: [(UIViewController, UIImage, UIImage)] = [
                 (cannabisVC, UIImage(named: "Cannabis_icon")!, UIImage(named: "Cannabis_icon_selected")!),
                 (profileVC, UIImage(named: "Profile_icon")!, UIImage(named: "Profile_icon_selected")!),

             ]

             let vcs = vcData.map { (vc, defaultImage, selectedImage) -> UINavigationController in
                 let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                 nav.tabBarItem.image = defaultImage
                 nav.tabBarItem.selectedImage = selectedImage

                 return nav
             }

             tabController.viewControllers = vcs
             tabController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
             tabController.delegate = tabBarDelegate

             // Disables rendering for tab bar images
             if let items = tabController.tabBar.items {
                 for item in items {
                     if let image = item.image {
                         item.image = image.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
                     }

                     if let selectedImage = item.selectedImage {
                         item.selectedImage = selectedImage.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
                     }

                     // Hides title
                     item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
                 }
             }

             // Customize Navigation bar
             UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x00ffcc)

            //
             window?.rootViewController = tabController
             self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
             // CREATE TAB BAR //

    } else {
        let loginStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
        let loginViewController = loginStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as! LoginViewController
        window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
    }

        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
```

**LoginViewController**

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var loginButton: UIButton!


    // MARK: - Properties
    let rest = APIClient()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func loginButtonDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text else { return }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }


        // MARK: URL
        guard let url = URL(string: APIClient.shared.loginURL) else { return }

//        rest.requestHttpHeaders.add(value: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forKey: "Content-Type")
        rest.requestHttpHeaders.add(value: "application/json", forKey: "Content-Type")
        rest.httpBodyParameters.add(value: "\(username)", forKey: "username")
        rest.httpBodyParameters.add(value: "\(password)", forKey: "password")

        rest.makeRequest(toURL: url, withHttpMethod: .post) { (results) in
            // MARK: Response
            print("\n\n### Response HTTP Headers ###\n")
            if let response = results.response {
                for (key, value) in response.headers.allValues() {
                print(key, value)
                }
            }
            print("\n\n### End Response HTTP Headers ###\n")

            // MARK: Data
            if let data = results.data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

                guard let item = try? decoder.decode(CustomUser.self, from: data) else { return }
                print(item.key)

                let userAuthToken = item.key
                UserDefaults.standard.set(userAuthToken, forKey: "key")

                Helper.login()

            } else {
                print("Unable to serialize data")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .medium)
                spinner.startAnimating()
                spinner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 44)
            }

       }

        print(username)
        print(password)
    }

}
```

**Helper Function** (This is basically the scene delegate but I plan to use this for logging the user in and out from within the ProfileViewController)

**Login/Out Functions** (I'm also getting a weak reference warning for TabBarDelegate, if anyone wants an extra challenge)

```
class Helper {
    class func login() {
        let tabController = UITabBarController()

           // Instantiate the storyboards
           let cannabisStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Cannabis", bundle: nil)
           let profileStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)


            // Instantiate the view controllers to storyboards
            let cannabisVC = cannabisStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Cannabis") as! CannabisViewController
            let profileVC = profileStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profile") as! ProfileViewController


            // Displays the items in below order in tab bar
            let vcData: [(UIViewController, UIImage, UIImage)] = [
                (cannabisVC, UIImage(named: "Cannabis_icon")!, UIImage(named: "Cannabis_icon_selected")!),
                (profileVC, UIImage(named: "Profile_icon")!, UIImage(named: "Profile_icon_selected")!),

            ]

            let vcs = vcData.map { (vc, defaultImage, selectedImage) -> UINavigationController in
                let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                nav.tabBarItem.image = defaultImage
                nav.tabBarItem.selectedImage = selectedImage

                return nav
            }

            tabController.viewControllers = vcs
            tabController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
            tabController.delegate = TabBarDelegate() (Weak reference warning here)

            // Disables rendering for tab bar images
            if let items = tabController.tabBar.items {
                for item in items {
                    if let image = item.image {
                        item.image = image.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
                    }

                    if let selectedImage = item.selectedImage {
                        item.selectedImage = selectedImage.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
                    }

                    // Hides title
                    item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
                }
            }

            // Customize Navigation bar
            UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x00ffcc)

           //
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        guard let window = appDelegate.window else { return }
        window.rootViewController = tabController
    }

    class func logout() {
        let loginStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
        let loginViewController = loginStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as! LoginViewController
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        guard let window = appDelegate.window else { return }
        window.rootViewController = loginViewController
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
struct CustomUser: Codable {
    static var current: CustomUser!
    var id: Int
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var email: String
    var photo: URL
    var token: String
    var key: String
}
```

**What happens**
As mentioned before, when I select the Login button in the LoginViewController, the token information is printed out but the login screen never moves to the main part of the app. I'm assuming the error is somewhere within storing the token in UserDelegate and verifying that it actually exists but I could be wrong.

I've tried searching Google but I mostly find tutorials on Auth0 (I plan to implement later on after a better understanding of what I'm trying to do now) and FireBase.

If there is a better way to implement what I am trying to do, I'm also willing to give that a try. If you have a reference to a tutorial I can view (and save for later), please share!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you get as far as printing out the headers then your code works almost the whole way through.  There's a guard statement shortly after that, when trying to decode the data to an instance of CustomUser, and I'm assuming that's where it's stopping.  Does the `print(item.key)` get executed?  If not, then you know that decoding the JSON is somehow failing, and you'll have to debug accordingly.  If, on the other hand, it's printing `item.key`, then the problem lies somewhere in the `Helper.login()` method

Comment: This solved my issue, I was not getting a token when printing item.key, so ran my token response in https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift and modified my CustomUser model to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`guard let window = appDelegate.window else { return }`
This will return as appDelegate.window is nil.

Make sure your code is setting UITabbarController on correct window of SceneDelegate.

Comment: `Synchronize()` is no longer necessary, check apple docs: `Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize)